# Define a new row in css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a way in css grid of saying 'after the second column, start another row'?

It seems straightforward enough defining how much height and width you want a grid cell to take up, but defining where you want cells to appear requires a lot of syntax - I feel like I'm missing something.

Like this layout:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
}

.block--one {
  background: coral;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.block--two {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.block--three {
  background: burlywood;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.block--four {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="block block--one"></div>
  <div class="block block--two"></div>
  <div class="block block--three"></div>
  <div class="block block--four"></div>
</main>
```

Shouldn't it be achievable with something like this?

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 5fr 1fr;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
}

.block--one {
  background: coral;
}

.block--two {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.block--three {
  background: burlywood;
}

.block--four {
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="block block--one"></div>
  <div class="block block--two"></div>
  <div class="block block--three"></div>
  <div class="block block--four"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Someone kindly formatted so we can see how the code renders. In short, I'm asking - how can we make the layout in the first example, with a simpler syntax like with the code in the second example.. it must be possible

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the code by using a shorthand property.

In your first example, you're using all long-hand properties. For example, you have this:

```
.block--two {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
```

Like with other CSS features, such as borders, margins and padding, there's a shorthand property to consolidate multiple lines of code.

In this case, there's the [**`grid-area`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) property, which shortens the code above to:

```
grid-area { 1 / 2 / 2 / 6 }
```

The values flow in this order:

1. `grid-row-start`
2. `grid-column-start`
3. `grid-row-end`
4. `grid-column-end`

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block--one {
  background: coral;
  /* no need to specify placement here; default aligns to row 1, column 1 */
}

.block--two {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / -1;
}

.block--three {
  background: burlywood;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4;
}

.block--four {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / -1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="block block--one"></div>
  <div class="block block--two"></div>
  <div class="block block--three"></div>
  <div class="block block--four"></div>
</main>
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

Answer (score 1):

A good way of defining the rows and columns can be by using `grid-template-areas` and `grid-area` which can define how many rows and columns a grid area should take up. This is especially helpful when changing the layout with `@media` tags, you only have to change the one attribute.

From your row and column definitions I can add each block to take up the space that I want it to.

See example for 2 rows by 4 columns for the 4 blocks.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "block1 block2 block2 block2"
    "block3 block3 block4 block4";
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
}

.block--one {
  grid-area: block1;
  background: coral;
}

.block--two {
  grid-area: block2;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.block--three {
  grid-area: block3;
  background: burlywood;
}

.block--four {
  grid-area: block4;
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="block block--one"></div>
  <div class="block block--two"></div>
  <div class="block block--three"></div>
  <div class="block block--four"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
}

.block--one {
  background: coral;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.block--two {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  grid-column: 2/ 6;
}

.block--three {
  background: burlywood;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.block--four {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="block block--one"></div>
  <div class="block block--two"></div>
  <div class="block block--three"></div>
  <div class="block block--four"></div>
</main>
```

grid-auto-flow: row; Will start on new row if the element is not able to fit on the current row

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the existing answers this question has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.